# What and Why my $HOSTNAME is hitronhub.home?

Tags: hostname

It has been a little while, let's say 3 weeks, that the initial line of my prompt is `b0:2a:43:7d:d1:3d:~ eduardoj$` instead of `passatempo:~ eduardoj$`. It has been like this, for every new sessions, even after rebooting.

But just new, a few of the sessions showed `passatempo:~ eduardoj$`. After noticing it again I decided to search what would that be. Having both tabs of my terminal still opened I ran
`echo $HOSTNAME`, which returned, respectively `b0:2a:43:7d:d1:3d.hitronhub.home` and 
`passatempo.local`.

I tried to google `hitronbub.home` and nothing made sense. I also saw some results here on stackoverflow that somehow related it to `docker`. Then I stoped all my containers and killed my daemon. After that, the new sessions I opened were still presenting the same `b0:2a:43:7d:d1:3d.hitronhub.home`.

Does anyone know what is it? Or, how could I track where it is causing it?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [How can I stop Mac OS X overriding my hostname when I receive a DHCP request on Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/q/49891/700114)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That answer tells how to avoid the symptoms. Now I am just wondering where that domain comes from, and how come I have two behaviours without changing networks. Since I suspected this whole thing could be related to networking, I disable the only thing I thought to be able to impact this, which is `docker`. I am not aware of any other application running that simulates a network other than the one I always used. As I said, for a long time it was `passatempo:~ eduardoj$` and now it has changed. My network configuration should still be the same, given that I didn't change them.